# jQuery - Detect if element height is bigger than window height and do something about it

Tags: jquery, window, height, element, detect

The tittle really says it all.

Basically i want to detect if this `div`'s `height` is bigger than `window` `height` and do something about it..

I have done this but i cant get it to work http://jsfiddle.net/dhkCa/3 Why wont it work?

Edit: Fixed a little error in the css code. Jsfiddle link updated.

Comment: if you alert the 2 values, you'll notice that the document height appears to be 20px greater than the div height [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/dhkCa/8/)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `document`'s contains all the elements within itself, and its height is a sum of the heights of all those elements (all the `display:block` elements anyway, plus margin and padding); therefore no contained element can be taller than the document itself. What you need to do is compare the `window`'s height, not the document's:

```
var div = $("div").height();
var win = $(window).height();

if (div > win ) {
    $("div").addClass('red');
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dhkCa/5/).

Comment: Right.. That is also clearly stated jquery api.. Once again I just failed to comprehend what I read. Thanks ( +1 ) and will be accepting when i can.

Answer (score 1):

For an element that has a scroll height that's different than the document's scroll height, you can use `element.getBoundingClientRect().height` [(Docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `.outerHeight()`, since `.height()` doesn't look at the padding of an element.

```
var div = $("div").outerHeight();
var win = $(window).height();

if (div > win ) {
    $("div").addClass('red');
}
```